# SQL trouble with complex php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good day,

I'm having a ton of trouble with the following php code,
the pseudo code for it as follow:

Check if a relationship exists in the table
if it doesn't exist add a relationship to the table.
otherwise get the current relationship and return it.

the code goes as follow:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user_id = '" .$me. "' AND user_id2 = '" .$other. "') OR (user_id2 = '" .$me. "' AND user_id = '" .$other. "')");
if($result == false){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `friends`(`user_id`, `user_id2`, `status`) VALUES ('" .$me. "', '" .$other. "', 'pending')");
    echo("Friend Request Sent"); 
}
else{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT 'status' FROM friends WHERE (user_id = '" .$me. "' AND user_id2 = '" .$other. "')");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows); 

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors? What is being returned currently?  What should be returned?

Comment: @Jrod it seems to skip the if statement and go directly to the else statement returning an empty JSON object, it should return "Friend Request Sent" on the ones not in the database

Comment: why didn't you try the same first query in else block?

Comment: @Ankur The first query won't work in the else block as it doesn't exist yet

Comment: I think you should check the result for an empty result instead of false.  False would indicate an error executing the query.  Your query seems to be valid and therefore if there is no match would produce an empty result set.  use mysql_num_rows() to check the returned results.

Comment: @Jrod I've searched and tried quite a bit of ways, but they don't seem to work correctly either, any suggestions in this context?

Comment: @Crossman still you should use the same query, as if the first query returns result then your else block would be executed and it might return null/empty object as condition is missing

Comment: @Ankur you mean to replace the else with another if statement and run the same query but check if its equal to true?

Comment: @Crossman again updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try the below if condition

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `friends`(`user_id`, `user_id2`, `status`) VALUES ('" .$me. "', '" .$other. "', 'pending')");
     echo("Friend Request Sent"); 
}
```

and also else block should be same as first query, and it should look like

```
else{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT 'status' FROM friends WHERE (user_id = '" .$me. "' AND user_id2 = '" .$other. "') OR (user_id2 = '" .$me. "' AND user_id = '" .$other. "')") ;
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
       $rows[] = $r;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows); 
}
```

Comment: That seems to wield the right results, I couldn't get the mysql_num_rows to work before though. Thank you